# Do not ignore spaces before when comparing

Tags: python, string-comparison

I have this list of strings:

```
['config firewall vip\n', '    edit "VIP"\n', '        config realservers\n', '            edit 1\n', '                set ip \n', '            next\n', '        end\n', '    next\n', 'end\n']
```

Then I have the following python code:

```
posIni = confCompleta.index('config firewall vip\n')
posFim = confCompleta.index('end\n',posIni) + 1
blocoVip = []
m = 0
for n in range (posIni,posFim):
    blocoVip.insert(m,confCompleta[n])
    m = m + 1
indiceInicialVip = [i for i, s in enumerate(blocoVip) if '    edit ' in s]
indiceFinalVip = [i for i, s in enumerate(blocoVip) if '    next\n' in s]
```

I don't want posFim to match the first "end" because it has spaces before. For the same reason the 'edit 1' should also not match in 'indiceInicialVip' because there are more than 4 spaces before it.How do I tell python not to ignore those white spaces? I want to match the whole line.

Comment: If you want to match the whole line, look for `'\nend\n'`.

Comment: Hi Jason, thank you for answering. It's not quite working cause the string is read by .readlines(). This way the \n is not before the 'end', it's in the previous line.

Comment: Please show the actual problem.  You claim that you have that input as a given string -- singular -- but in your comment say that it's in a series of lines.  Please initialize `confCompleta` hard-coded to make this a proper [Minimal, complete, verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: If these are individual lines, then the problem is pretty easy: the final `end` is where the index is 0.

Comment: It will be better if you edit the post instead of placing that in a comment